# Can I customize the Save As Dialogs Save-Button in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, save-as

Is it possible to customize WPFs Save As-Dialog in a way, so I can add additional Save options like in this mock?

[image]

I guess, it's not possible out of the box, so I would also appreciate any link/hint on how build your own SaveAs-Dialog.

Comment: Try to look to this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy

Comment: Thank you, @StefanoBafaro for answering. I know this codeproject article and the one actually talking about WPF: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42008/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-Using-WPF
But both don't show a way how to manipulate the buttons.